# SQLite query returns no rows

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

I am trying to get a simple SQLite database working. I'm using the official SQLite extension for C# and I'm using DataGrip from IntelliJ to verify the data is there, yet my C# program doesn't get any results.

This is the code that executes the query:

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(DbDsn);

User user = new User();

using (connection)
{
    connection.Open();

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = @username ;";
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection);
    command.Prepare();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);

    SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.Read())
    {
        user.Id = (int) reader["id"];
        user.Username = reader["username"] as string;
        user.Password = reader["password"] as string;
        user.Name = reader["name"] as string;
        user.LastName = reader["last_name"] as string;
        user.Type = (UserTypes) reader["type"];
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ObjectNotFoundException();
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

And this is the result of a simple `Select * From user;` query on the user table (done on DataGrip):

```
id  username    passw…  name    last_name   type
1   managertest oAWpW…  BENJAMIN ARIEL  NAVA MARTINEZ   1
2   clerktest   iRYMz…  EMPLEADO    PRUEBA  0
```

As you can see, the records are there (an I've verified that the query is being performed on the exact same file), however, the C# program seems to skip the `if` statement (because read returns `false`) as if there were no rows in the database, what is the problem here?

Comment: add command.Prepare(); after  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `SQLiteCommand.Prepare` **AFTER** you have completed constructing your command

```
//...
string sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = @username ;";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
// Call Prepare after setting the Commandtext and Parameters.
command.Prepare();

SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
//...
```